# Python/Flask/MongoDB - error message: BadRequestKeyError: 400 - Get list

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mlab

I'm a newbie to this, so please forgive me if I haven't properly explained myself. I'm creating an online store for a project. I want to have a multiple select list that a user can pick from. I'm using Python, Flask and MongoDB/mlab to store and retrieve the data. So far it looks like this:

```
@app.route('/update_item/<item_id>', methods=['POST'])
def update_item(item_id):
    store = mongo.db.store
    store.update( {'_id': ObjectId(item_id)},
    {
        'name':request.form['name'],
        'type':request.form['type'],
        'color':request.form['color'],
        'material':request.form['material']
    })
    return redirect(url_for('main_store'))
```

The HTML it looks like this:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('update_item', item_id=item._id) }}" method="POST" class="col s12">
 <select id="material" name="material" value="{{store.material}}">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
     <option value="denim" name="denim">Denim</option>
     <option value="cotton" name="cotton">Cotton</option>
     <option value="viscose" name="viscose">Viscose</option>
     <option value="silk" name="silk">Silk</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

But I keep getting this error message

```
BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'material'
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, 
in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, 
in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, 
in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, 
in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, 
in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, 
in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, 
in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, 
in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app.py", line 74, in update_item
'material':request.form['material']
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist- 
packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 431, in __getitem__
raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'material'
```

What am I doing wrong? 'name', 'type' and 'color' work just fine on their own. I tried the below, but this didn't fix it either. Thanks.

```
'material':request.form.getlist['material']
```

Comment: The cause of the error is not obvious from what you sent. Please include full template code (or at least the `form` part).

Comment: Oh, okay - whoops. I have updated it to include the form part.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you provided complete traceback, not only exception name.

Comment: Updated to include complete traceback - thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this as your html

```html
<select id="material" name="material" placeholder="Select">
    <option value="denim">Denim</option>
    <option value="cotton">Cotton</option>
    <option value="viscose">Viscose</option>
    <option value="silk">Silk</option>
</select>
```